# Ajuda na compreensão sobre construção pronominal em Dom Quixote

Tags: português-brasileiro, gramática, pronomes, colocação-pronominal, literatura

Estou lendo atualmente o clássico Dom Quixote e me deparei com uma construção pronominal que estou tendo dificuldade para entender. A passagem em questão é a seguinte:

*"**Encheu-se-lhe** a fantasia de tudo que achava nos livros, assim de encantamentos, como pendências, batalhas, desafios, feridas, requebros, amores, tormentas, e disparates impossíveis; e ***assentou-se-lhe*** de tal modo na imaginação ser verdade toda aquela máquina de sonhadas invenções que lia, que para ele não havia história mais certa no mundo."*

Minha dúvida está relacionada à construção **"encheu-se-lhe"** e **"assentou-se-lhe"**. O uso duplo de pronomes aqui me confunde. O que exatamente essa construção significa neste contexto ? Também gostaria de saber o nome específico dessa construção pois não tenho certeza se chama "ênclise dupla".

Agradeço antecipadamente pela ajuda e pela clarificação desta questão.

Comment: a fantasia se encheu para ele de a, b e c. E: na imaginácão dele se assentou etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vamos por partes. Primeiro o *se*:

> A fantasia encheu-se de tudo...

Neste caso, estamos perante um *se* anticausativo. Assim, temos:

> A chuva encheu o poço de água. (versão causativa; sujeito *a chuva* toma o papel de Fonte)
>
> O poço encheu-se de água. (versão anticausativa; sujeito tem o papel de Tema, que é o objeto direto na versão causativa)

Verbos deste género chamam-se verbos de alternância. Na verdade, com *encher*, o *se* não é obrigatório. Em português brasileiro, ainda menos é, embora dependa da região. Em português europeu, *o poço encheu de água* parece-me uma opção duvidosa, mas *o poço encheu* é melhor do que *o poço encheu-se*. No texto que citaste, temos uma versão com objeto oblíquo, por isso, ao meu ouvido, a versão com *-se* é melhor.

Em relação a *assentou-se*, temos:

> Assentou-se na imaginação ser verdade que...

onde *ser verdade que* é o sujeito. Aqui, a frase já me soa estranha. Não é que *assentar-se* não exista, mas *assentar-se* é normalmente usado quando significa *sentar-se*. Diria:

> O depósito assentou no fundo da garrafa.

mas:

> Eles assentaram-se à mesa.

Mas enfim, a ideia é a mesma. Temos uma construção transitiva de *assentar* (*ele assentou o filho à mesa*) e uma construção anticausativa (*ele assentou-se à mesa*).

Quanto ao *lhe*, é o chamado *dativo de posse* (como em *dói-me a cabeça*):

> Encheu-se-lhe a fantasia de coisas = A fantasia dele encheu-se de coisas

Em português europeu, é possível redobrar o clítico:

> Encheu-se-**lhe** a **sua** fantasia de coisas

Acontece o mesmo com *assentar* e *imaginação*.

Quanto ao facto de haver dois clíticos, a combinação *se* + *dativo* é permitida (ao contrário da combinação *se* + *acusativo*, que só é permitida nalguns dialetos). O pronome *se* tem de ocorrer antes do dativo *lhe*. A mesma ordem ocorreria com próclise:

> Não se lhe encheu a imaginação.

Comment: Esse uso dobrado também acontece em lei brasileira. Por exemplo, no [ECA](https://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/leis/l8069.htm) no Art.3º há a frase "assegurando-se-lhes".

Answer (score 1):

Essa construção na verdade é um castelhanismo; a [versão original](https://gutenberg.org/cache/epub/2000/pg2000-images.html) traz:

> **Llenósele** la fantasía de todo aquello que leía (...) tormentas y disparates imposibles; y **asentósele** de tal modo en la imaginación...

Naquele idioma, é uma construção corriqueira para substituir o pronome possessivo; de modo que os espanhois não dizem *lastimó* [machucou] *su mano*, mas sim *se lastimó la mano*. Então a sequência original, se traduzida num português mais castiço porém mas informal, diria:

> A fantasia dele se encheu de tudo que achava (...) disparates impossíveis; e a ideia se assentou na sua imaginação de tal modo de tudo aquilo ser verdade...

Então, sob certo aspecto, o *se* no texto faz a vez de pronome possessivo.

Comment: O dativo de posse é o "lhe", não o "se".

Comment: encher-se existe em português: https://dicionario.priberam.org/encher-se E assentar-se também.